# How to load a block of a binary file into a vector at a time using C++ stl

Tags: c++, stl, ifstream

As the question suggests, how do I load a block of a binary file into a vector at a time using C++? I suppose using `ifstream_iterator` to solve the problem, but I am not familiar with it. Can anyone give me some code of copying 200 data from a file into a vector at a time? Note that I am using a `.bin` file, so my data must be binary.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are somewhat more likely to get an answer to this question if you show us what you have tried so far, and how the data you intend to read into memory looks like.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

> When reading characters, std::istream_iterator skips whitespace by
> default (unless disabled with std::noskipws or equivalent), while
> std::istreambuf_iterator does not. In addition,
> std::istreambuf_iterator is more efficient, since it avoids the
> overhead of constructing and destructing the sentry object once per
> character.

`ifstream_iterator` is not designed to be used to read binary files, we need to use `istreambuf_iterator` instead, and open file with  `std::ios::in | std::ios::binary` flags

A sample code may like this:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string fname{"you_file"};
  std::ifstream ifs(fname, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter(ifs);
  std::vector<char> vec(iter, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});

  std::cout << "bytes:" << vec.size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If you have multiple files to read, then wrap the code snippet into a function and call it with a loop.